# How do I declare a static array with volatile elements?

Tags: c, arrays, volatile

### Clarification about terminology used:

For static array I mean array statically memory allocated like: int x[10].

### **The problem**

I need to declare a static array with volatile elements. 
If I well understood how volatile qualifier works, it should be:

```
volatile uint8_t *x; // x is a pointer to volatile uint8_t
uint8_t *volatile x; // x is a volatile pointer to uint8_t
volatile uint8_t *volatile x; // x is a volatile pointer to volatile uint8_t
```

Ok, but now I need to do the same thing with a **static array**.
I tried with:

```
volatile uint8_t x[10];  // Only the pointer is decleared as volatile
uint8_t volatile x[10];  // Same as above
volatile uint8_t *x3[10]; // Casting problems and errors when I do ...  
*x3[0] = 1; // ... something like this. Moreover, I do not know if this...
            // ... statement declares the uint8_t element as volatile
```

Thanks!

### UPDATE

Ok, as highlighted in the comments I should use:

```
volatile uint8_t x[10]
```

As I could understand, the problem is not in the declaration but in the usage of this variable in my code. I pass this element to a function whose prototype is:

```
static void functionName(uint8_t *buffer, uint32_t size);
```

I call the function in this way:

```
functionName(x, 10);
```

The compiler reports: **passing argument 1 of 'functionName' discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type**

I can't change the function prototype, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: First of all, arrays are *not* pointers. Arrays can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but it's not a pointer in itself. Secondly, the declaration `volatile uint8_t x[10];` declares `x` to be an array of 10 `volatile uint8_t` elements.

Comment: I suggest you to "clarify" your ideas by a `typedef` where you define your data type 'volatile uint8_t *'

Comment: If you have problems with passing function parameters, you might update your question to include the function prototypes and the error messages.

Comment: If you cannot change the prototype, it is impossible to tell `functionName` that the objects are volatile. You could make a copy of the data you want to pass to `functionName` and pass that. E.g., allocate some memory or declare a local array, copy the data from `x` into that memory, and pass that memory to `functionName`. Of course, then `functionName` will not see any changes to `x` that occur during execution of `functionName`. You will essentially have a non-volatile snapshot of `x`. If `functionName` changes the data, then, when it is done, copy the temporary data back into `x`.

Comment: Either you need a volatile array or you don't. You can't have an array which is "sometimes volatile" or "slightly volatile". If you need a volatile array, it is a bug to pass it to a function which isn't volatile-qualified, because doing so doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Arrays cannot be stored in registers (because of their size) and for that reason `volatile` is not necessary. Is this compiler message warning or error?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do to declare a static array of 10 volatile elements of type `uint8_t`is just:

```
volatile uint8_t x[10];
```

Be aware that this is a declaration of an array, which has nothing to see with pointers at this step.

*Note: Later in your code, if you use `x`, it may decay to a pointer to the first volatile element, but in this case this pointer will have a constant value, given at the linking step. The pointed value is obviously volatile.*

Comment: Actually, when I use: `volatile uint8_t x[10]` the compiler reports **passing argument 1 of 'functionName' discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type**, where argument 1 is x. So, it seems that it is the pointer [to the first element] to be declared as volatile.

Comment: @igol You must also add `volatile` to your parameter list of the function. Otherwise the function cannot know that it mustn't optimize accesses to that memory location.

Comment: @igol I agree with Gerhardh. If you call a function `functionName(x)`, then the prototype of the function must be like `void functionName(volatile uint8_t* ptr)`, in order that the data pointed by `x` is considered as volatile in the function code.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across the problem myself today.
A variable CAN be 'sometimes' volatile.
Being volatile means, that its value can changed outside the program flow. By a parallel thread or an ISR.
Now if the ISR is what changes the value 'unexpectedly', it won't change unexpectedly inside the ISR itself. So for the ISR, the variable is not volatile and disabling compiler optimizations for it is counterproductive.
If I call a function from inside the ISR (and only from there), then the variable is not volatile and I don't want to pass a pointer to volatile, as it would produce inefficient code.

For this case, the solution I found was to have two declarations:

```
int a[x] = {};
volatile int * b = a;
```

Now the outside world uses b (globally declared in the header file) and treats the values pointed to by b as volatile, while the ISR (locally) defines both and uses a, treating the values as being not volatile.

Well, this is a very special case. In general, a function only sees the function parameter declaration. Which is either volatile or not, so the funciton will treat a parameter either always as being volatile or always as being not. It cannot automatically switch between two maybe completely differently compiled code blocks depending on the original volatile qualifier state of the passed parameter. Hence the warning.